# How to setup parsing emails?

Tags: python

How do I setup a server so I can get emails and parse them in python?

Comment: Have you read about Python's  SMTP, POP and IMAP libraries yet?  Perhaps you should read those first, then ask your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing emails as soon as they are received](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529075/parsing-emails-as-soon-as-they-are-received)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question, so you are going to get a pretty broad answer.  I'd recommend looking into [Twisted Mail](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/mail/examples/).  Also, Python has an [email library](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html) for parsing.  Python has an smtpd library as well, but I prefer Twisted personally.

Comment: thanks, i mean just the process of receiving the email itself, and setting up a process to do so

Comment: @Timmy: Then there is example code on the Twisted page I linked to for a simple SMTP server.

Comment: thanks, ya, im reading it now, was just clarifying the question

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of services on the web that will make it easier for you to send and receive e-mails using their API. This would relieve you from the pain of setting up, running and administrering your own e-mail service.