# Process incoming emails with Python script

Tags: python, email

I'm trying to process all incoming emails (to a specific catch-all account -- spam ) with a Python script.
I've followed the advise of several other online questions
( [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/206477/processing-incoming-emails-with-python/206479#206479) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529075/parsing-emails-as-soon-as-they-are-received) )

But I can't seem to get the script to run.

If I:  `cat mytestemail | path_to_my/script.py`  the script will run against mytestemail

But when I add the entries to /etc/aliases , nothing seems to happen.

Postfix is configured to use virtual-alias-maps, so I'm not sure if that's different than /etc/aliases  --  Regardless, I've tried configuring both files.

I want the script to process against all email that gets delivered to the 'spam' folder.

Here is what the virtual-alias-maps file looks like:

```
user1@mydomain.com           user1 
user2@mydomain.com           user2
@mydomain.com                spam 
spam                         |/home/ubuntu/Script.py
```

Here is what the aliases file looks like:

```
# See man 5 aliases for format
postmaster: webmaster@mydomain.com
spam: |/home/ubuntu/Script.py
```

Adding the entry to the virtual-alias-maps prevents mail delivery, but just adding the file to the /etc/aliases seems to do nothing.

Here is a stripped version of my main.cf

```
# Debian specific -- Default PostFix settings
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf -m "${EXTENSION}"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot


#Customized Dovecot and virtual user-specific settings
canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
home_mailbox = Maildir/
message_size_limit = 104857600
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual-alias-maps
virtual_mailbox_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual-mailbox-domains
virtual_transport = dovecot

## This setting will generate an error if you restart Postfix before adding the appropriate service definition in master.cf, so make sure you get that taken care of
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1

## Customized milter settings
milter_default_action = accept
milter_connect_macros = j {daemon_name} v {if_name} _
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
smtpd_milters = unix:/opendkim/opendkim.sock

# Other customized mail server settings
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 5
disable_vrfy_command = yes
relay_destination_concurrency_limit = 1

# Unused Settings
defer_unauth_destination
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use `sendmail -bv` to debug the problem.
(sendmail command provided by postfix)

As local OS user execute `/usr/sbin/sendmail -bv no-such-user@mydomain.com`.
It should show which part of rewriting chain does not work as expected
(virtual alias -> local alias -> command)

[Debugging Postfix from inside](http://www.postfix.org/DEBUG_README.html#trace_mail)